# "Loop" inside of "While Loop" goes infinite

Tags: excel, vba

So I have some code that was working great as long as my data ends with a range that has values.

It looks in my range to see if all cells are blank and if it is I want it to skip to the next row. However, as you can probably imagine this causes problems once I get to the bottom of my data it will just keep going forever.

Is there a way I can put some type of check in to stop this from erroring out once I reach the bottom of my data.

My "While" does not stop it unless I end with a range that has data. Because it gets stuck in this loop.

I am using excel 2013 if that matters.

```
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(RowCount, 4)) 'loops all code

i = 1

Do Until i = 2 

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    Set rng = ws.Range("F" & RowCount & ":N" & RowCount)
Else
    i = 2
    'test'rng.Select
End If


Loop

Wend
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 loops here? Where do you instantiate `RowCount`? What is `ws`? Please include all of your code. I think a single `Do While` is all you need here.

Comment: The `Do until i = 2` is the main issue, because if `else i=2` does not trigger in the loop, i will always 1, therefore infinite loop happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Blank (`CountBlank`) vs Empty (`CountA`) Row Ranges

- Adjust the values in the constants section and the worksheet (workbook).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub BlankRowRanges() ' Blank means: Empty, "", "'" ...

    Const sFirst As String = "D2"
    Const sCols As String = "F:N"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ' Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' is better.
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range.
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim scCount As Long
    With ws.Range(sFirst)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Worksheet.Columns(sCols).Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1) _
            .Offset(.Row - 1)
        scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    End With
    'Debug.Print srg.Address, scCount
    
    ' Loop through each row (range) of the Source Range.
    Dim rrg As Range
    For Each rrg In srg.Rows
        If Application.CountBlank(rrg) = scCount Then
            ' Do something more meaningful.
            Debug.Print "The range '" & rrg.Address & "' is blank."
        Else
            ' Do something more meaningful.
            Debug.Print "The range '" & rrg.Address & "' is not blank."
        End If
    Next rrg

End Sub

Sub EmptyRowRanges() ' Empty

    Const sFirst As String = "D2"
    Const sCols As String = "F:N"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ' Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' is better.
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range.
    Dim srg As Range
    With ws.Range(sFirst)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Worksheet.Columns(sCols).Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1) _
            .Offset(.Row - 1)
    End With
    'Debug.Print srg.Address
    
    ' Loop through each row (range) of the Source Range.
    Dim rrg As Range
    For Each rrg In srg.Rows
        If Application.CountA(rrg) = 0 Then
            ' Do something more meaningful.
            Debug.Print "The range '" & rrg.Address & "' is empty."
        Else
            ' Do something more meaningful.
            Debug.Print "The range '" & rrg.Address & "' is not empty."
        End If
    Next rrg

End Sub
```